# Vertical line in NSTextView

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

I want to create a rich text editor like the one that is used in Mail.app. The NSTextView basically supports everything that I need, except one thing. I can't figure out how to create vertical lines like Mail.app does for quoted text.

For reference, this is a screenshot of a threaded discussion that illustrates what I am talking about:

[image: Threaded discussion in Mail.app]

I'm referring to does two vertical lines on the left side of the image. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

CoreText is probably the answer here. See the documentation at 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/LayoutOperations/LayoutOperations.html
especially listings 2.3 and 2.4, which show laying out text in a column and doing so within drawRect: where you also draw a vertical line or lines up the left side of the rectangle.

CoreText allows you to do just about anything with text and layout. I'd highly recommend a recent series of 5 videos on CoreText at http://www.nsscreencast.com/episodes